# Issue receiving FCM notifications on some iOS 14.6

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I have reports of users on iOS 14.6 not receiving notifications. This seems to only affect iOS users on 14.6, not other versions nor Android. All users are using our latest app's version.

I was able to remotely test things with such a user:

- I checked that his iPhone properly registers for push notifications (our back end properly saves the corresponding device ID).
- I tried sending push notifications to a specific subject, both using our back office as well as the Firebase Console. I properly receive them on iOS 14.6 but he didn't.
- The user correctly receives notifications from other apps.

Has anyone encountered that kind of issues?

What could I test knowing that I do not have access to the iPhone that has the issue?

I'm using Cordova with https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push .

Comment: tbh it sounds like a iOS14.6 bug

Answer (score 0):

Same my issue. I found reason why. Please check your `registerRemoteNotification` function. We have a note `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` must be call after `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization` completed. I hope help you.

```swift
func registerRemoteNotification(completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        
        let application = UIApplication.shared
       
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {granted, error in
                //
                // granted == true  --> selected 'Allow'
                // granded == false --> selected 'Don't Allow'
               
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                
                Analytics.setUserProperty(granted.description, forName: "notification_enable")
               
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }
        })
        
    }
```